# How to prevent double quotes being enclosed by single quotes

Tags: bash, shell

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I honestly don't know what to search for. So please consider this tiny script:

```
#!/bin/sh
test="\"Hello\" \"World\""
set -x
echo $test
```

The result will be this:

```
+ echo '"Hello"' '"World"'
"Hello" "World"
```

But that's not what I want! I don't want to have single quotes around the `echo` arguments. What I want to have is this instead:

```
+ echo "Hello" "World"
Hello World
```

How can I achieve that please?

*** EDIT ***

Here is a more specific example on the real problem behind the illustration above:

```
#!/bin/sh

alldirs=

for d in */ ; do
    dir=${d%?}
    alldirs+=" \"$dir\""
done

set -x
tar cvf test.tar.gz $alldirs
```

The idea is to archive all directories in the script's directory in a tar archive. Since directory names may contain spaces, I'm enclosing their names in double quotes.

The script above doesn't work. `tar` complains about not being able to run `stat` on the individual directories because of the double quotes.

Comment: Related: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#Things_that_do_not_work

Comment: The single quotes are only used because `set -x` uses them as a means to show the what is intended to be echoed; the actual echo will not contain single-quotes.

Comment: I know, but now imagine `$test` is passed to `tar` instead and both `Hello` and `World` are files to be archived. `tar` will say `File not found` because of the single quotes. That's actually my problem...

Comment: Show the actual command you are referring to, as using arbitrary examples in questions is mostly pointless... double-quoting `echo "$test"` should be sufficient not word-split/glob the value.

Comment: Added specific example to OP.

Comment: Now put your script in shellcheck.net and follow the suggestions.

Comment: How about avoiding the whole issue and doing something like: `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvfz test.tar.gz`. That will pass the directory names to `tar` correctly (note the `print0` and `-0` options). And you need one of the compression options for `tar` and actually get compression.

Comment: Have you read [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)? Do. Seriously. The difference between literal and syntactic quotes is **critical** to understand to use the language correctly.

Comment: @gilez, that wouldn't behave so well if you had more names than will fit on a single command line (if they exceed `ARG_MAX`); you'd end up running `tar` more than once, and only the names included in the last invocation would be used.

Comment: (What you're literally asking for is to have literal quotes be treated as if they were syntactic ones. Strictly speaking that's possible, via use of `eval`, but it's a Very Bad Idea -- the distinction is what makes it possible to handle untrusted data in bash safely; see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for some discussion, and keep in mind that injection attacks aren't just a SQL thing).

Comment: Thanks guys, got the difference between literal and syntactic quotes now. You're right, this is critical, but I'm only writing shell scripts once in a year or so and so I always tend to forget lots of stuff in the meantime. Will add some comments now to my script :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed about the argument overflow, but that's a problem that exists in the original, in a different form. The details were 'left for the reader' :-) But `tar` does have a `--concatenate` option to deal with this.

Comment: @gilez, ...*nod* -- I consider the explicit-failure form much less worrisome than the silently-incorrect-output version. If someone hits the former, they're much more sure to *notice* and ask about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I snoooped on your history and saw that you're familiar with C-like languages:

```
int main() {
  char *s = "\"hello\", \"world\"";
  printf("First: %s, second: %s\n", s);
}
```

You're expecting this to be equivalent to

```
printf("First: %s, second: %s\n", "hello", "world);
```

Instead, it writes:

```
first: "hello", "world", second:
```

So why is `printf` adding extra quotes? The answer is obviously that it doesn't. It's not `printf`'s job to interpret quotes. Literal quotes don't affect how a C function receives strings.

Similarly, it's not `echo` or `tar`'s job to interpret quotes. Literal quotes don't affect how a shell command receives strings.

The solution in both C and bash is to put the values in an array, rather than trying to create one string with embedded quotes in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
alldirs=()

for d in */ ; do
    dir=${d%?}
    alldirs+=("$dir")
done

set -x
tar cvf test.tar.gz "${alldirs[@]}"
```

This is of course just for illustration. A real script would simplify this to `tar cvf test.tar.gz */`

Comment: Thanks for the C example, C's pretty much my mother tongue, so I've understood my error now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just for the record, I can't use `*/` because I need to leave out some directories. But your array approach works fine.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks ^_____^

Comment: @Andreas, re: `*/` but without some explicit matches, there's actually an `extglob` syntax for that. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for your exact script, but you don't need to use double-quotes.

You can just try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
test=Hello\ World
set -x
echo $test
```

Comment: Sorry, that won't solve the problem. The code above in the OP is just an illustration for a problem which is more complex. Generally speaking I'm looking for a way to pass a variable that contains double quotes to a program but I don't want bash to enclose all the double quotes inside single quotes. The double quotes should be passed literally.